# Showing wrapped bean property in JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx-2, javabeans

I'm trying use a TableView to show some data the user created, but, unfortunately, some specifics columns contents aren't shown. The columns with problem are a kind of two level bean, or in another way, a wrapped bean:

*Getters and setters are ommited*

```
public class ItemBean {

    private VisaoProdutoPreVenda produto;
    private BigDecimal quantidade = new BigDecimal("0.0");
    private BigDecimal valorUnitario = new BigDecimal("0.0");
    private BigDecimal valorDesconto = new BigDecimal("0.0");
    private BigDecimal valorAcrescimo = new BigDecimal("0.0");
    private BigDecimal aliquotaDesconto = new BigDecimal("0.0");
    private BigDecimal aliquotaAcrescimo = new BigDecimal("0.0");
    private Integer ordem;
    private String idVendedor;
    private Boolean fracionado = false;
    private boolean cancelado = false;
    private String status = "AB";

}

public class VisaoProdutoPreVenda{

    private int id;
    private int idProduto;    
    private BigDecimal valorDesconto;
    private BigDecimal quantidadeDisponivel;    
    private BigDecimal vlUnitario;
    private int idEmpresa;    
    private Integer idLinha;
    private int idClasse;    
    private int idSubclasse;
    private String nomeLinha;    
    private String unidade;
    private String descricao;    
    private String descricaoComplementar;
    private String fracionar;    
    private int idTipoDesconto;

}
```

I want use three fields of VisaoProdutoPreVenda bean in the table, so I tryied this:

```
public class ControladorPainelPreVenda {

    ...

    @FXML
    private TableView<ItemBean> tabelaItens;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn colunaCodigo;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn colunaDescricao;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn colunaLinha;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn colunaQuantidade;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn colunaValorLiquido;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn colunaValorTotal;
    private ObservableList<ItemBean> itens = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    ...

    private void configurarTabela() {

        /* These three first columns content aren't shown */

        colunaCodigo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ItemBean,String>("produto.id"));
        colunaDescricao.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ItemBean,String>("produto.descricao"));
        colunaLinha.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ItemBean,String>("produto.nomeLinha"));
        colunaQuantidade.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ItemBean,BigDecimal>("quantidade"));
        colunaValorLiquido.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ItemBean,BigDecimal>("valorLiquido"));
        colunaValorTotal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ItemBean,BigDecimal>("valorTotal"));
        tabelaItens.setItems(itens);
    }

    ...
}
```

I don't know if I can use a notation like "produto.id" in PropertyValueFactory. How I could configure these three columns to show the content I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem implementing Callback interface:

```
public class MultiPropertyValueFactory<B,T> implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<B, T>, ObservableValue<T>> {

    private String propriedade;

    public MultiPropertyValueFactory(String propriedade) {
        this.propriedade = propriedade;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<T> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<B, T> dados) {
        Object elemento=dados.getValue();
        String propriedades[]=propriedade.split("\\.");
        for(int indice=0;indice<propriedades.length;indice++){
            elemento=recuperarElemento(elemento,propriedades[indice]);
        }
        return new SimpleObjectProperty<T>((T) elemento);
    }

    private Object recuperarElemento(Object elemento,String propriedade) {
        try {

            /*using reflection here*/

            Method metodo = RecuperadorMetodos.recuperarMetodoGetPeloNomeDaPropriedade(elemento.getClass(),propriedade);
            return metodo.invoke(elemento);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

and passing objects of this class to setCellValueFactory() method:

```
private void configurarTabela() {
    colunaCodigo.setCellValueFactory(new MultiPropertyValueFactory<ItemBean,String>("produto.id"));
    colunaDescricao.setCellValueFactory(new MultiPropertyValueFactory<ItemBean,String>("produto.descricao"));
    colunaLinha.setCellValueFactory(new MultiPropertyValueFactory<ItemBean,String>("produto.nomeLinha"));
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TableView` is going to search for `*Property` methods before it searches for getters, so I would first set my beans up so that my fields are `[type]Property`'s (e.g.

```
public class VisaoProdutoPreVenda{
    private SimpleIntegerProperty id;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty idProduto;
    ...

    public SimpleIntegerProperty idProperty(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

Then I would expose the properties of `VisaoProdutoPreVenda` from the `ItemBean`.

```
public class ItemBean {
    private VisaoProdutoPreVenda produto;
    ...
    private String status = "AB";

    public SimpleIntegerProperty produtoIdProperty(){
        return produto.idProperty();
    }
}
```

Change your `PropertyValueFactory` setup for those fields to mirror the change in your beans.

```
colunaCodigo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ItemBean,Integer>("produtoId"));
```

Comment: if I create in ItemBean a `getProdutoId()` simply returning `return produto.getId()` it is the same code without any change to the properties... Perhaps a better solution is create my own `CellValueFactory`.

Comment: Your alternative should work fine. Note that if you ever want to allow editing in the `TableView` then you'll need to either switch to using properties or go ahead and implement a custom `CellFactory`. The `CellValueFactory` will work but without the binding, you would have to handle the edits manually.